# Check if value exists in list - View Calendar

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

i created a list and use the view Calendar. Now Need to block duplicates values ​​with the same hours and days..

I would like to use 3 keys( Date Start, Date End and Room of Event ), before the user to insert in the lists i need to check, if that there are this values..

The Calendar of Sharepoint, do it, but is limited..

I've tried to create an indexed field but not solved ..

thank you...

Comment: You'll need a custom workflow using something like Nintex or custom event handler that reacts to a new/update item.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do it with OOB functionality. It will be necessary to develop custom event receiver handling itemadding and itemupdating events. Inside the event receiver you can check duplicates, display error and prevent add or update action.